# Add a percentage Fee with a fixed Fee to Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

In Woocommerce, I would like to add 3% processing fee plus 30 cent “fixed” fee to the checkout page.

I have managed to add the processing fee, using the code mentioned below:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, true, '' );
}
```

Now, I just need to add the 30 cent “fixed” fee. How can I achieve this?

I’ve tried, adding:

```
$fee = 0.30;
```

But, it didn’t work for me.

Comment: what's in `add_fee()` function? does it return a value?

Comment: Did you try adding `.30` to your `$surcharge` variable value…?

Comment: I do not see `$fee` anywhere in your code. Are you asking how to do math in PHP?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus would that actually surprise you on this site :-) …

Comment: @misorude sadly, it does not surprise me. I find less and less reason to participate every time I come here :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit outdated, try the following instead that will add a fixed fee to the percentage fee:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woocommerce_custom_surcharge' );
function woocommerce_custom_surcharge( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 0.03;
    $fixed_fee  = 0.3;

    $percentage_fee = ( $cart->cart_contents_total + $cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
    $surcharge  = $fixed_fee + $percentage_fee;

    $cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, true );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> When using this hook outdated `$global $woocommerce;` is not needed as the hooked function can use the `WC_Cart` object variable as an argument…

Comment: Your code is working great! 

Is it possible to make this code work, for orders above 100$  (only)?

Comment: @UsamaShabbier Add before `$percentage = 0.03;` this line `if( $cart->subtotal <= 100 ) return;` … You can only target the subtotal in this hook.

Comment: Thank You. You are really a Legend ❤️

Sorry to bother you again, but I've one last question: 

- How do I make this code work for only small order? I want to apply the processing fee for only small orders (below 100$).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have both surcharges added in a way that allows them to be displayed separately you could:

```
$percentage = 0.03;
$fixed_fee = 0.30;

$surcharge = ( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage;
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, true, '' );
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Fixed fee', $fixed_fee, true, '' );
```

If you do not need to display them separately and just note that the "processing fee" includes a 3% surcharge plus a fixed 30 cents:

```
$percentage = 0.03;
$fixed_fee = 0.30;

$surcharge = (( $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total ) * $percentage) + $fixed_fee);
$woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Processing Fee', $surcharge, true, '' );
```

both should work. It'll depend on what you need downstream